# Question : Minimal routes through preferred vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I need help to solve this question:

you have a graph G=(V,E) , nodes pair s ≠ t ∈ V and you have subset of nodes U ⊆ V Which exists ø ≠ U ≠ V and s,t ∉ U.
for each path P we mark it L(P) the length of the path (number of edges in the path) and #P(U) number of the nodes U in the path, write an algorithm to find a path between from s to t that should visit U **exactly 2 times** And the minimum length of all these tracks.
In other words the algorithm should return a path from s to t where #P(U)=2 and lets say we have another path P' from s to t where #P'(U)=2 then L(P)≤ L(P') 
( it is permissible for the track to pass through A certain vertex more than once) .
Help : use graph reduction G'

Comment: Hey, no offense but I don't think anyone will help you out.  And that's because you just seek help without showing _what you did_ and _where exactly you are stuck_.  You will have to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your chances.

Comment: Make sense , but really i am stuck in it

Answer (score 0):

Divide the trajectory into 5 steps
`{s} ∪X → U → X∪ {ε} → U → X∪ {t} where X = V \\ (U∪ {s, t}) (X` group of vertices out of V that are not Preferred vertices, neither s nor t) which will ensure that #P (U) = 2 and we will use BFS to find the shortest route.

Algorithm -
Constructed from G (V, E) New directional graph G ^ '= (V ^', E ^ ') as follows:
Each preferred vertex u∈U, we add twice to V ^ 'so u_4∈V ^', u_2∈V ^ '. We will add s and t to the new graph and for each x∈X vertex we will create x_1, x_3, x_5 in the new graph.

```
For each arc (s, x) ∈E | x∈X, {(s, x_1)} ∈E ^ '
Per arc (s, u) ∈E | u∈U, {(s, u_2)} ∈E ^ '
For each arc (x, u) ∈E | x∈X, u∈U, {(x_1, u_2), (x_3, u_4)} ∈E ^ '
Per arc (u, x) ∈E | u∈U, x∈X, {(u_2, x_3), (u_4, x_5)} ∈E ^ '
Per arc (u, u ') ∈E | u, u'∈U, {(u_2, u_4 ^ ')} ∈E ^'
Per arc (u, t) ∈E | u∈U, {(u_4, t)} ∈E ^ '
For each arc (x, t) ∈E | x∈X, {(x_5, t)} ∈E ^ '
```

We will now run a BFS scan on graph G 'starting from s. For the first appearance of t in the scan, the trajectory from s to t (after lowering the labels for there to be a trajectory in G) is the shortest trajectory that satisfies the question conditions. If no t is found in the scan - then there is no such trajectory.
The correctness of the algorithm -
#P (U) = 2 - By defining the graph G 'we guarantee that each trajectory from s to t will pass exactly twice in the vertices of U (this can be seen by labeling the vertices to stages 1-5 and arcs that always progress in stages without the possibility of skipping stages 2 and 4 where there are vertices of U).
The shortest route - using a BFS scan ensures acceptance of the shortest route, because the scan is performed at levels when a vertex that appeared at an earlier level - will not appear at a later level.

Finally, the labels are lowered to ensure that the route is in G.
Complexity of the algorithm -
The graph G 'is constructed by going over all the vertices and arcs of G once and therefore ran in Θ (m + n), scanning BFS over G' running in Θ (m + n) (by BFS runtime) and we obtained that the runtime The total is Θ (m + n).

Answer (score 0):

Previous solution presented by 'evyatar weiss' is partial, since it's not considering the fact that you can move within X uninterruptedly (U is limited to 2 vertices per route, but X is not limited). Following is an example of a graph to which this solution will not work (I added in pencil the missing vertices in order to fix it).
[image]

In order to solve this, the following vericies should be added to G':

```
For each arc (x,x')∈E | x,x'∈X, {(x_1, x'_1), (x_3, x'_3), (x_5, x'_5)}∈E'
```